# How to populate select list with JSON from API?

Tags: jquery, json, api, loops

I have JSON response from API call like so:

```
{
"results": {
"AF": {
"alpha3": "AFG",
"currencyId": "AFN",
"currencyName": "Afghan afghani",
"currencySymbol": "؋",
"id": "AF",
"name": "Afghanistan"
},
"AI": {
"alpha3": "AIA",
"currencyId": "XCD",
"currencyName": "East Caribbean dollar",
"currencySymbol": "$",
"id": "AI",
"name": "Anguilla"
},
"AU": {
"alpha3": "AUS",
"currencyId": "AUD",
"currencyName": "Australian dollar",
"currencySymbol": "$",
"id": "AU",
"name": "Australia"
},

... and so on
```

I am trying to populate select list:

```
<select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality"></select>
```

using jQuery:

```
        var url =
          "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/countries?apiKey=[apiKey]";

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
           

            $("#locality-dropdown").append(
              '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + "</option>"
            );
          });
        });`
```

to get name of the country as my text and currency ID as my option value but all I get is [object object]. Can anyone tell what to add to "value" so its loop through the given data?

Answer (score 1):

You where close...

The `data` resulting from the `$.getJSON()` resquest is an object.

It seems it as one `results` property holding another object.
In that inner object are many other objects holded by some *maybe unknown* property names...

Using `$.each()` will work fine on an `array`. For some nested objects, it is slightly different.

In the `for in` loop I used, `item` is (in turn): `AF`, `AI`, `AU`...

I don't know which property of those *"most inner"* objects you wish to use... But assuming you'd want `name`:

```js
let getJSON_response = {
  "results": {
    "AF": {
      "alpha3": "AFG",
      "currencyId": "AFN",
      "currencyName": "Afghan afghani",
      "currencySymbol": "؋",
      "id": "AF",
      "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    "AI": {
      "alpha3": "AIA",
      "currencyId": "XCD",
      "currencyName": "East Caribbean dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "AI",
      "name": "Anguilla"
    },
    "AU": {
      "alpha3": "AUS",
      "currencyId": "AUD",
      "currencyName": "Australian dollar",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "AU",
      "name": "Australia"
    }
  }
}

// Replacing the $.each loop with a for in loop:
//
for (item in getJSON_response.results) {

  // Get the name property of each most inner object
  let name = getJSON_response.results[item].name

  // Use it in the append
  $("#locality-dropdown").append(
    '<option value="' + name + '">' + name + "</option>"
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality"></select>
```

Comment: Worked in first go

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more efficiently by building the options as an html string and then mutating the `<select>` only once. Also, it looks like you want to iterate over the `data.results`, not the `data` itself. Last thing to mention, `$.each()` works differently iterating over objects than it does for arrays. For an array it's `function(index, value)`, but for an object it's `function(key, object)`. In this code, the `key` will be the `country_abbreviation` and the `object` will be the `country` (or data for that country)

```
$.getJSON(`https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/countries?apiKey=[apiKey]`, function (data) {
  let optoins_html = ``;

  $.each(data.results, function (country_abbreviation, country) {
     options_html += `<option value="${country.currencyId}">${country.name}</option>`;
  });

  $("#locality-dropdown").html(options_html);
});
```

Also, as a personal preference, if you're not going to use the `url` else where in your code, there is no point in setting it to a variable, you can just use it right in the `$.getJSON()` function. It's more readable this way and there is no chance of accidentally mutating it elsewhere in your code.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals